# Return a Calculated Array within Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, average

I'm trying to return a calculated array within Excel and was curious if it was possible.

Imagine a table with 3 fields, Fruit, Count, and Cost.

Fruit can appear multiple times. Count is equal to how many were purchased at any given time. Cost is equal to the unit cost per fruit.

If I were to want to know the average amount spent on a specific fruit, I have the formula {=AverageIf(A2:A10, "apples", count*cost)}. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Sure I can create the formula myself in another row, but I'm trying to avoid this.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? I have given two different methods below. You will be returning a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array formula

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A10="Apples",B2:B10*C2:C10))
```

Entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A10="Apples"),B2:B10,C2:C10)/COUNTIF(A2:A10,"Apples")
```

This should be in a cell outside of the data area.

Comment: This does work. Thank you. I've used the AVERAGEIF function so often that I assumed it functions similarly to using the IF function in conjunction with the AVERAGE function.